# Flex 3 prevent duplicate stacking in ColumnChart control

Tags: apache-flex, charts

Here is my Problem:
I'm currently using a ColumnChart to display 6 label/value pairs.
When two labels are the same, the chart stacks them up, one on top of the other.
I want to display these duplicates side by side, their value might be the same or it might be distinct.

- My first thought was to append a unique id to the label, but that's not possible according to the client. So, is there a way to tell the chart to also take a hidden id into consideration?
- Someone suggested to do some sort of grouping, but I need to display each chart separate, as if they were distinct charts.

the chart's data provider is an array of these objects:
obj.description = "des";
obj.countV = 3;//some arbitrary number
obj.id = 2; //a unique id...

the chart code:

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution:
append an index # at the end of each column label.
Use a labelFunction to remove the last char:
columnLabel.slice(0, -1);
that fooled the chart into thinking they're all uniques but display all duplicates side by side.